Unexpected sort order in bootstrap-table
Not sure if I'm doing something dumb or what, but I have a table initialized with data='table'
A header like
<th data-sortable="true" data-field='col_display_name' class="text-center th-lg "scope="col">{% trans site_display_name_header %}</th>

And data that looks like this
<td class="ml-5">
    <a href="{% url 'sites:site_detail' site.id %}">{{ site.site_display_name }}</a>
</td>

However sorting the column just seems to toggle the sort between the default order and the reverse order, and doesn't seem related to the data in the column (site.site_display_name)
Other columns in the table are setup the same way and seem to sort correctly based on the values in the column.
There is no leading or trailing characters or anything that stands out that would make me think it is sorting correctly.
My understanding from the bootstrap-table documentation is that if you use data-toggle='table' it automatically figures out the structure of the data and value specified in data-field='col_display_name' can really be anything  you want to call it (as long as its unique I imagine).
Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

hey, core dev of the bootstrap-table here.
Without a runnable example i can only guess the issue, but i guess the issue is that the column contains html.
The bootstrap-table sorts by the raw value (in you're case the html) instead of the displayed value.
But the SortName option should solve this issue. You will also find an example there.

Thanks for the response, I ended up pivoting away from bootstrap-table, so I'm unable to see if that was the issue any more.
